# Getting type error in function haskell

Tags: haskell

I have these functions, which someone one from stackoverflow told me while trying to explain a concept, but when I tried running it, I get a lot of errors.

```
type World = [String]

removeItem :: String -> World -> IO World
removeItem item world = do
  if elem item world
    then do putStrLn "Item removed."
            return $ delete item world
    else do putStrLn "No such item - " ++ item
            return world

removeTwoItems a b world = do
  world1 <- removeItem a world
  world2 <- removeItem b world
  return world2

look :: World -> IO World
look w = do
  putStrLn $ "You see these items here: " ++ show w
  return w

loop w = do
  words <- fmap words getLine
  case words of
    ("quit":_) -> return ()
    ("look":_) -> do w' <- look; loop w'
    ("remove":item:_) -> do w' <- removeItem item w; loop w'
    _ -> do putStrLn "huh?"; loop w

main = do
  let world0 = ["chair", "bucket"] -- the initial world
  loop world0
```

The errors are:

```
prac.hs:12:13:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type ‘IO ()’
    In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely
      ‘putStrLn "No such item - "’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn "No such item - " ++ item

prac.hs:12:13:
    Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘IO’
    Expected type: IO Char
      Actual type: [Char]
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn "No such item - " ++ item
    In the expression:
      do { putStrLn "No such item - " ++ item;
           return world }
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      if elem item world then
          do { putStrLn "Item removed.";
               return $ delete item world }
      else
          do { putStrLn "No such item - " ++ item;
               return world }

prac.hs:29:28:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘IO World’
                with actual type ‘World -> IO World’
    Probable cause: ‘look’ is applied to too few arguments
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: w' <- look
    In the expression:
      do { w' <- look;
           loop w' }
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Could somebody explain me this or fix this?

Answer (score 5):

Function application has higher precedence than any operator, so

```
putStrLn "No such item - " ++ item
```

means

```
(putStrLn "No such item - ") ++ item
```

You need to write

```
putStrLn ("No such item - " ++ item)
```

or use the `$` operator which is function application with lower precedence 
instead, like this:

```
putStrLn $ "No such item - " ++ item
```